# date_create_from_format AND DateTime::createFromFormat functions breaking on Server

Tags: php, datetime, server, localhost

I recently uploaded my client's site onto a temporary server so that they could get started on data input while I fine tune the design.

When I launched it however, one of my sliders and one of my pages broke down completely [note: this only occurs on the server side; my localhost site continues to work perfectly].

I narrowed it down to my use of the date_create_from_format() function as I use it on both pages, and when I remove the element holding that bit of php, the site works fine. I have scoured my file for any missing semi-colons, or brackets, and I can't find any glaring errors. Here is my code as it was orginally on my localhost.

```
<p>
              <?php 
                $end = date_create_from_format('Ymd',$ending_date);
                $start = date_create_from_format('Ymd',$starting_date);
                echo "<span class='month'>" . $start->format('F') . "</span>";
                echo " ";
                echo "<span class='day'>" . $start->format('j') . "</span>";
                echo ", ";
                echo "<span class='year'>" . $start->format('Y') . "</span>";

                echo " - ";

                echo "<span class='month'>" . $end->format('F') . "</span>";
                echo " ";
                echo "<span class='day'>" . $end->format('d') . "</span>";
                echo ", ";
                echo "<span class='year'>" . $end->format('Y') . "</span>";
                echo ", $location";
               ?>           
            </p>
```

I have also tried converting it from the object to the procedural function (See below) but the result is the exact same.

```
<p>
                  <?php 
                    $end = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd',$ending_date);
                    $start = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd',$starting_date);
                    echo "<span class='month'>" . date_format($start,'F') . "</span>";
                    echo " ";
                    echo "<span class='day'>" . date_format($start,'j') . "</span>";
                    echo ", ";
                    echo "<span class='year'>" . date_format($start,'Y') . "</span>";

                    echo " - ";

                    echo "<span class='month'>" . date_format($end,'F') . "</span>";
                    echo " ";
                    echo "<span class='day'>" . date_format($end,'d') . "</span>";
                    echo ", ";
                    echo "<span class='year'>" . date_format($end,'Y') . "</span>";
                    echo ", $location";
                   ?> 
              </p>
```

Thank you "Sysix" for the answer regarding assigning a timezone. I made the following adjustment (See below) but the problem persists.

```
    <?php 
  $end = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', $ending_date, new DateTimeZone('America/Toronto'));
  $start = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', $starting_date, new DateTimeZone('America/Toronto'));
 ?>
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment: Your PHP Version ist 5.2.17

but DateTime::createFromFormat is avaible since PHP 5.3

Look at the doc: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Comment: IT WORKED! Oh my god thank you so much! I feel like such a dumb dumb as I have pent literally a week trying to solve this assuming I was making some sort of syntax error, and never thought to check my versions.

You are a life saver!

Answer (score 0):

I have found a notice, that DateTime::createFromFormat ignore the setted TimeZone. You must set the Timezone explicit for the object.

http://php.net/manual/de/datetime.createfromformat.php#116027

Comment: Made an adjustment but problem persists. (See above).

Any thoughts?

Comment: Which PHP Version have you installed on the server? Have you error_reporting on?

Comment: Current PHP version: 5.2.17

No. I don't really know what that is. Where should I have that running? the <head>?